# Hair Particle grows different on curved mesh

Tags: particles, hair

I have a mesh, a plane, and it is supposed to be a landscape with grass. It has some ups and downs not a flat plane. When adding the hair(grass). I did some weight paint to tell where the grass should grow. It seems to be more grass on lower parts of the mesh for some reason. The strange thing is that it looks fine in the viewport but not after rendering in Eevee. I have played around with the settings but can't find any solution. Would appreciate any help here.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image1]

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by another plane that forgot to disable in render, as well as in the viewport.

Comment: Another user may find the information useful if they happen across the same problem at some point. It is always much more useful for future users of the site to write your complete solution than not to.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes reloading/reopening your blender file helps to force eevee to use the recalculated particles. It might be using a cached version.

Comment: Unfortunately not. It is llike it is calculating the growing from center not the surface but I can't find any settings for it.

Comment: Are the particles (a) where you don't want them weight paint wise, or (b) are they not conforming to the ground properly (growing in mid air)? If it's 'a' then make sure there's 0 weight in the vertex group where you've painted/erased the weight fully blue, as in select the group in edit mode and make sure there are no verts. in the group where you don't want grass. If it's 'b'- is the ground displaced (modifier) and if so is the displace mod. above the particle mod. in the stack, and if that's OK have you chosen 'use modifier stack' in the particle settings emission/source drop-down?